# Running scalapbc command from a thread pool

Tags: scalapb

I am trying to run the scalapb command from a threadpool with each thread running the `scalapbc` command;

When I do that, I get an error of the form :

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f32dd71fd70, pid=8346, tid=0x00007f32e0018700
```

As per my google search, this issue occurs when the /tmp folder is full or it is trying to be accessed by multiple code simultaneously.

My question is, is there a way to issue scalapbc commands using threading without getting above error? how to make sure that the temp folders being used by the individual threads don't interfere with each other?

This issue occurs most of the times when I run the code but sometimes the build passes as well.

Comment: Can you post a complete reproducible example that triggers this problem?

Comment: @thesamet, apologies for delayed reply; due to work being office related, will not be able to post the code here; will see if I can recreate the problem using a simple example and post here; thanks for the help.